# How add tier price to all child product of configuable product magento 2

Tags: magento-2.1

**Preconditions**
Magento version 2.1.x

**Steps to reproduce**

1. Create one product configurable
2. Config child product list
3. Set tier price for all child product

In magento 1, if i need set tier price to all child product with same price, i set tier price at product configuable, it so easy.
Actual result

In magento 2, if i want set a tier price for all child product, i have to go every child product to config it, if i have 20 30 child product or more than, i have do it 20 30 time ?

How do it easier?

Answer (score 0):

We can still setup tiers price for configurable products (which apply for all child products) when we create new product, but we cant edit it later.

1. Go to Admin-Product-Catalog: add new configurable product
2. In base setting-product details tab: fill name, sku, price then SAVE
3. Now you can see advanced pricing in advanced setting tab